# What does the following error mean- No Scaffold widget found?

Tags: flutter, dart

even i try to get alert dialog, this message always come

[image: Error dialog]

Comment: try wrapping your widget with Scaffold.

Comment: Try adding the error as text to the question. Please show us your (relevant) code and what you have tried in an effort to resolve the error.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, using `showModalBottomSheet` rather `showBottomSheet` worked